# Xcode 15 shows simulator in Devices but also shows`simulator not installed` in the run destination and preview

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode15

I have downloaded and installed iOS 17 simulator runtimes and copied the `profiles` folder alongside the other old simulators at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/`.

Now Xcode shows simulators in the [<kbd>Device And Simulators</kbd> window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnyLa.png), **But** it's NOT working as a [running destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlRDi.png) and thinks the iOS 17 simulator is not installed!

[image: Both windows]

What is the issue? Quit and reopening Xcode doesn't help and I don't want to redownload 8.0GB of simulator again!

Comment: Same here. In my XCode Settings >>  "Platform" tab it shows that I have the "iOS 17.0 Simulator" and "iOS 17.0.1 Simulator installed" but it also shows the greyed out "iOS 17.0 ... GET". Clicking it and downloading it does not help. Also re-installing XCode, Restarting the Mac and Manually adding it with ``xcrun simctl runtime add ...`` does not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it appear in runtime destination and preview, you should copy the runtimes to:

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/
```

Instead of:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/
```

> `~` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I eject the runtime image from Disk Utility.app, and restart macOS to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT copy the simulator runtimes but instead leave them in your Downloads folder.  We updated the documentation to clarify this:

**[Install Simulator runtimes from the Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes)**

Starting with Xcode 15, you can select the platforms you want to download from the Apple Developer website.

Select the checkbox next to each platform you want to develop for, and then click the Download button. This initiates downloading Xcode, the selected platforms, and a manifest file to your Downloads folder. Don’t move the simulator and manifest files outside the Downloads folder during installation. When the selected simulator and manifest files finish downloading, Xcode automatically installs them from the Downloads folder.

Comment: 1. it didn't appear in my experience.

Comment: 2. I may need this for Xcode 14 and there will be no Xcode installation at all!

Comment: 3. where is the source of "should NOT"?

Comment: 4. Sorry for the multiple comments. It's not allowed newlines in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded iOS 17 runtime from the developer website
you should run this command to install it. Copy pasting the absolute path didn't work for me.

```
xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"
```

Comment: Did not work for me :-/ ...

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Xcode. When you list runtimes everything looks fine:

```
xcrun simctl runtime list       
== Disk Images ==
-- iOS --
iOS 17.2 (21C62) - E13CDAC4-5C23-4C79-AA9C-A23EBBB9DFC9 (Ready)
```

But in fact the disk image is not mounted at the `mountPath`. One way to solve it is to remove problematic image with `xcrun simctl runtime delete` and then run `xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS` to restore it. Then destinations are visible in Xcode.