# Simulators don't show up as run destination in Xcode 15.0

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15

Since upgrading to Xcode 15.0, I have not been able to set simulators as a run destination. They do not show up as an option in the menu (either in the dropdown from the toolbar, or in the `Product > Destination` menu). However, they do show up in the `Devices and Simulators` window. They also open happily by themselves (when opening from `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator`), but projects still will not recognize them as a possible run destination.

I have tried making many changes, with no luck:

- Marking several simulators to 'always' show up, instead of automatically
- Making new, custom simulators
- Including both architectures under `Product > Destination > Destination Architectures`
- Deleting and redownloading my copy of iOS 17
- Running new or pre-existing projects
- Running iOS only and multi-platform projects
- Restarting Xcode and restarting my computer

Xcode will connect and run apps on my phone (iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 17.01). Interestingly, the canvas for SwiftUI says "Loading iOS 17.0...", but it never actually loads (though it will preview on my phone). I would think this points to an issue with my iOS 17 download, but the simulators seem to boot just fine. Many of these attempted fixes were inspired by answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414829/xcode-15-shows-simulator-in-devices-but-also-showssimulator-not-installed-in-t).

Running `xcrun simctl list` yields a long list of simulators:

```
== Device Types ==
iPhone 6s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s)
iPhone 6s Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus)
iPhone SE (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE)
iPhone 7 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7)
iPhone 7 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7-Plus)
iPhone 8 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8)
iPhone 8 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8-Plus)
iPhone X (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X)
iPhone Xs (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS)
iPhone Xs Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS-Max)
iPhone Xʀ (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XR)
iPhone 11 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11)
iPhone 11 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro)
iPhone 11 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-11-Pro-Max)
iPhone SE (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE--2nd-generation-)
iPhone 12 mini (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-mini)
iPhone 12 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12)
iPhone 12 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-Pro)
iPhone 12 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-Pro-Max)
iPhone 13 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-13-Pro)
iPhone 13 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-13-Pro-Max)
iPhone 13 mini (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-13-mini)
iPhone 13 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-13)
iPhone SE (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE-3rd-generation)
iPhone 14 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-14)
iPhone 14 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-14-Plus)
iPhone 14 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-14-Pro)
iPhone 14 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-14-Pro-Max)
iPhone 15 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-15)
iPhone 15 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-15-Plus)
iPhone 15 Pro (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-15-Pro)
iPhone 15 Pro Max (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-15-Pro-Max)
iPod touch (7th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPod-touch--7th-generation-)
iPad mini 4 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-4)
iPad Air 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2)
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro)
iPad (5th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--5th-generation-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-)
iPad Pro (10.5-inch) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-)
iPad (6th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--6th-generation-)
iPad (7th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--7th-generation-)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (1st generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--11-inch-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---3rd-generation-)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--11-inch---2nd-generation-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---4th-generation-)
iPad mini (5th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini--5th-generation-)
iPad Air (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air--3rd-generation-)
iPad (8th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--8th-generation-)
iPad (9th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-9th-generation)
iPad Air (4th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air--4th-generation-)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-11-inch-3rd-generation)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-12-9-inch-5th-generation)
iPad Air (5th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-5th-generation)
iPad (10th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-10th-generation)
iPad mini (6th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-mini-6th-generation)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-11-inch-4th-generation-8GB)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) (16GB) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-11-inch-4th-generation-16GB)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-12-9-inch-6th-generation-8GB)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) (16GB) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-12-9-inch-6th-generation-16GB)
Apple TV (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p)
Apple TV 4K (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-4K)
Apple TV 4K (at 1080p) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-1080p)
Apple TV 4K (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-2nd-generation-4K)
Apple TV 4K (2nd generation) (at 1080p) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-2nd-generation-1080p)
Apple TV 4K (3rd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-3rd-generation-4K)
Apple TV 4K (3rd generation) (at 1080p) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-3rd-generation-1080p)
Apple Watch Series 2 (38mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm)
Apple Watch Series 2 (42mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm)
Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm)
Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm)
Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-4-40mm)
Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-4-44mm)
Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-5-40mm)
Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-5-44mm)
Apple Watch SE (40mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-SE-40mm)
Apple Watch SE (44mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-SE-44mm)
Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-6-40mm)
Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-6-44mm)
Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-7-41mm)
Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-7-45mm)
Apple Watch SE (40mm) (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-SE-40mm-2nd-generation)
Apple Watch SE (44mm) (2nd generation) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-SE-44mm-2nd-generation)
Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-8-41mm)
Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-8-45mm)
Apple Watch Ultra (49mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Ultra-49mm)
Apple Watch Series 9 (41mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-9-41mm)
Apple Watch Series 9 (45mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-9-45mm)
Apple Watch Ultra 2 (49mm) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Ultra-2-49mm)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 17.0 (17.0 - 21A328) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-0
== Devices ==
-- iOS 17.0 --
    iPhone SE (3rd generation) (C9B93C6E-6F5C-4885-A1B5-FBDCBB31C462) (Shutdown)
    ez (196EDFD8-C5A9-45A5-A7AC-2B39E07055B8) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 (857F0720-4BE4-40B6-A755-D38E1E53608F) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 Plus (3936179C-96B4-4947-A6C6-883130058909) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 Pro (89F1FBF8-5A76-4E94-B948-3DACCBF7AFBF) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 15 Pro Max (BADA1F50-197A-4FD0-89CF-1F8F10B99149) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air (5th generation) (217163A8-1FA1-4E96-BC9C-8BA436A4E880) (Shutdown)
    iPad (10th generation) (A6820111-FDF8-4EA3-B573-FDDD72D5A0A6) (Shutdown)
    iPad mini (6th generation) (19DA9216-4EC7-4DD8-9688-840C8A3FE8B4) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) (D1BFB2C4-C752-452A-B700-730FBC8D2EAA) (Shutdown)
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) (87322B2B-FD56-4B07-B254-B61816E33B83) (Shutdown)
== Device Pairs ==
```

My computer is a MacBook Pro M1 Pro running Ventura 13.6. I'm hesitant to update to Sonoma before resolving this issue.

Comment: I have this same exact issue after recently updating from Xcode 14.3 to Xcode 15.0.1. Everything was working alright and nothing shows up except "iOS 17.0 Not Installed" as the destination (which I have issue installing too as I don't have enough disk space). Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I manage to make them appear again by successfully installing that iOS 17 simulator runtime. However my older iOS simulators (though installed) were not appearing for some reason as if they were removed, and only 14.4/15.5/17.0.1 were showing up. This is probably Xcode 15 restriction. As I am still on Ventura I will install back Xcode 14.3 to get back my older iOS simulators (< iOS 14). Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I reopened Xcode 6 weeks later, it reinstalled a new version of iOS (17.0.1), and it seems to be working perfectly now. I have no idea what changed. Good luck to all who come here for answers, do continue sharing what worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, I was using Xcode 15.0 on MacBook Pro/M2 Pro/Sonoma 14.1.1, and I could not access some of the simulators. They appeared as a potential device in the Devices & Simulators window, but not as an option for running the app.

I was trying to use an iPhone 8 Plus to get 5.5" screenshots for App Store Connect.

I was able to access this simulator plus others by downloading the iOS 15.0 Simulator. At first, I only had iOS 17.0 as an iOS option.

XCode > Settings > Platforms Tab >
Click '+' in bottom left of screen > iOS... > Choose iOS Simulator (for me, iOS 15.0 worked) > Download & Install.

After iOS 15.0 Simulator was installed, I could access other simulators that were previously only visible in the Devices & Simulators window.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! My Xcode seems to have sorted itself out now for reasons beyond my comprehension. Glad you were able to sort it out with this! I'm not marking this as correct because I wasn't able to test this, but thank you for posting it! It gave me hope.

Comment: Came here to say that this fixed it for me. All I had to do was install the iOS 17.2 runtime that XCode 15.1 was forcing on me. Once I did that, all my previous run destinations appeared in the dropdown.